# Wordpress Rotating Background Images

Tags: jquery, images

I would like to be able to create a rotating background image that resizes with the browser window. I would like to also be able to set a certain amount of images to rotate per page or at the least start at a random number.

Here is an example > http://www.theme-dutch.com/presents/screen/

Is there a plugin for this? I am assuming it's Jquery.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) to make your background-images stretch to cover the area of the box.

If you then create a containing box positioned absolutely over the whole page, you can put your slides in there.

At that point it is just a matter of fading them in and out, something which can be easily done via a jQuery plugin like [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

**Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnAqE/1/**

As you can see all you need to do to add slides is create a new child `div` for `#slideshow`. In WordPress this can be done by looping over your gallery images.

Related reading:

- [Supersized – Full Screen Background/Slideshow jQuery Plugin](http://buildinternet.com/2009/02/supersized-full-screen-backgroundslideshow-jquery-plugin/)
- [Advanced jQuery background image slideshow](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/advanced_jquery_background_image_slideshow.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at their [js-file](http://www.theme-dutch.com/presents/screen/wp-content/themes/Screen1.4/js/functions.js).